# What is the structure of 2-methylimidazolate?

Tags: nomenclature

Looking for the structure of 2-methylimidazolate, I find conflicting results:

- this page on [sodium 2-methylimidazolate](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/summary/summary.cgi?sid=87677887&viewopt=PubChem) gives:
  [image]
- this other page on [cadmium 2-methylimidazolate](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.24770682.html) gives another anion, namely a carboxylate derivative of 2-methylimidazole:
  [image]

Which is it? Where in IUPAC nomenclature rules can I get the definitive answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand the IUPAC nomenclature, 2-methylimidazolate would not be the correct name for either structure.

The term imidazolate refers to the anion of imidazole, though it is not really the correct suffix according to the proposed revision of the [IUPAC blue book](http://old.iupac.org/reports/provisional/abstract04/BB-prs310305/Chapter7.pdf) (P72.1):

> Method (1) leads to preferred IUPAC names. Some names and some
>   contracted names are retained as preferred IUPAC names and for use in
>   general nomenclature. The following suffixes are used:
>
> - ‘ide’ (corresponding to removal of a hydron, H+),
> - ‘uide’ (corresponding to the addition of a hydride, H−),
> - ‘elide’ (corresponding to the addition of an electron)
>
> The endings ‘ate’ and ‘ite’ are used to indicate removal of a proton
>   from a −OH group of acids and hydroxy compounds.

The correct term for the imidazole anion would be imidazolide, and not imidazolate as imidazol is neither an acid nor a hydroxy compound.

In both database entries the IUPAC name mentioned is not imidazolate, this seems to be a trivial name for those structures. So my suspicion would be that both have been called imidazolate at some point, but this does not seem to be the correct IUPAC nomenclature for either of them.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple sources use **2-methylimidazolate** to denote the following *exo*-bidentate ligand with the structure:

[image]

For instance, [1, p. 210] reviews coordination polymers of transition metals, where $\ce{Hmim}$ ([2-methylimidazole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Methylimidazole)) is the main precursor for the $\ce{Cu(I)}$ and $\ce{Ag(I)}$ complexes. Polynuclear complexes were also obtained for $\ce{Fe(II)}$, $\ce{Co(II)}$, $\ce{Cu(II)}$, $\ce{Zn(II)}$ zeolitic
methylimidazolate frameworks [2,3].

Tetrakis(dicarbonyl-(2-methylimidazolate)-rhodium(I)) [4] was one of the first structures of coordination polymers obtained *via* single-crystal x-ray diffraction where **2-methylimidazolate** ligand (and the name therein, abbreviated as $\ce{2-MeIm}$) was used:

$\color{#EEEEEE}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{H}$; 
$\color{#909090}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{C}$; 
$\color{#3050F8}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{N}$;
$\color{#FF0D0D}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{O}$;
$\color{#0A7D8C}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Rh}$.

[image]

As expected for the drawn structure of 2-methylimidazolate ligand above,

> the four 2-methylimidazolate rings are perfectly planar.

#### Bibliography

1. *Modern Inorganic Synthetic Chemistry*; Xu, R., Pang, W., Huo, Q., Eds.; Elsevier: Amsterdam, **2011**. ISBN 978-0-444-53599-3.
2. Rettig, S. J.; Storr, A.; Summers, D. A.; Thompson, R. C.; Trotter, J. *Canadian journal of chemistry* **1999**, 77 (4), 425–433.
3. Park, K. S.; Ni, Z.; Côté, A. P.; Choi, J. Y.; Huang, R.; Uribe-Romo, F. J.; Chae, H. K.; O’Keeffe, M.; Yaghi, O. M. *Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences* **2006**, 103 (27), 10186–10191.
4. Tiripicchio, A.; Camellini, M. T.; Uson, R.; Oro, L. A.; Ciriano, M. A.; Pinillos, M. T. *Journal of Organometallic Chemistry* **1982**, 224 (2), 207–216. DOI [10.1016/S0022-328X(00)89040-3](https://doi.org/10.1016/s0022-328x(00)89040-3).